# Grant a user to give grant for another user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible to give grant to user by another user? I've created user with full privileges:

```
CRETAE USER test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO test@localhost;
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO test@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But when I tried to give privileges to another user using user 'test' It is written "Access denied to user test@localhost for table 'x'"

Updated: I found the way by edditing Grant_priv mysql.user is there any syntax for that?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

```
CREATE USER test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO test@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
...
```